# ubuntu 16.04 でインストールした mysql-5.7 に対して、 root のすべてのアクセスを grant したい

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

vagrant 上の ubuntu16.04 (box 名称 ubuntu/xenial64) に、 mysql をインストールしようとしています。このサーバーは、ひとまず host <-> guest のネットワークのみから、アクセスできるようにしています。 (IP 指定で private_network を指定している。)

この上にインストールした mysql に対して、ホストからアクセスしたいです。現状だと、以下のエラーが発生します。

```
$ mysql -h 192.168.33.20 -uroot
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.33.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

少しネットで検索した結果、 `grant all` をやればよい、と書いあるのが多いので、ゲスト(ubuntu) の中で、それを実行してみた結果が次です。

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%';
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

#### 質問

- どうやったら、任意のホストからの root アクセスを、このサーバーに対して許可することができますか?

  - 開発用で、プライベートネットワークに閉じた範囲でしかアクセスできない用途で使うので、セキュリティはなくてもいいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRANT の前にユーザーを作る必要があります。

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%';
```

以前は GRANT が CREATE USER も兼ねてたのですが、今は別になったようです。